# Disappear button after 7 days Laravel Javascript

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using a button for refund order within 7 days.
I want to disappear that button after the 7 days of order delivery.

My Orders Controller is:

```
public function show(Eorder $order)
{
  $expired = Eorder::where('id', $order->id)->whereDate('delivered_at', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))->get();
   return view('auth.single-order')->with([
         'expired' => $expired,
         'order' =>  $order,
    ]);
  }
```

My view

```
@if($expired)
@else

<button type="submit" class="view-order" style="margin-left:5px;"> {{ __('Refund') }} 

@endif
```

Comment: What goes wrong with your implementation, i.e. what is your question?

Comment: The button should disappear after 7 days of **delivered_at** date. But its not working

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel, but it looks like `$expired` is not defined in `@if` condition, as the variable is defined as a local variable in `show` method ..? Maybe it's also better to define an `unexpired` variable instead of `expired` ..?

Comment: what are you doing with `$expired` in the if statement? if it is true continue in the if statement? but what is `$expired` ? is it a boolean, int or what?

Comment: `get` returns a Collection which is an object which is always `true` ... you want to call `exists` instead of `get` to get a boolean of whether the record exists

Comment: try $expired = Carbon::make($order->delivered_at)->diffInDays(Carbon::now()) > 7;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. First I converted the string into int days by adding this code to my Model:

```
protected $casts = [
        'delivered_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    ];
```

Then I called the passed days from $order->delivered_at in my Controller like this

```
$days = $order->delivered_at->diffInDays(today());
```

In the last I called the $days in my blade view:

```
@if($days > 7)
Refund date passed.
@else
Refund
@endif
```